# outlook 2003 coding standards

Tags: html, css, outlook

What are the html coding standards to be kept in mind while designing an html email for outlook 2003 and prior versions?

Should only inline css be used?

Should we stop using css altogether and just  use the table attributes for styling?

There is shortage of information on the internet for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortage of information is due to there being a lack of standards. In a nutshell, everyone does their own thing.

To ensure the very best reception of your email, just use plaintext and attach any necessary stylized documents. Or, a link to a webpage. (Note that some email clients initially refuse to anything but plain text until the user manually permits it) ([More information on plain-text vs CSS](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) )

If plain text emails aren't acceptable, then go on right ahead of CSS. In-line CSS and CSS inside the `<head></head>` tags are virtually the same regarding support for them. (See here : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ )

Answer (score 3):

In short, to answer your direct questions:

- Use inline CSS only
- Don't stop using CSS alltogether, but find a good balance

This subject is too broad to be answered in a single answer. Great resources can be found on the website of CampaignMonitor. You will not find a single more complete resource on the internet:

- http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2003 and prior used the same rendering engine as IE 5 so basically code like you are in quirks mode. In outlook 2007 they greatly neutered the rendering capabilities by switching to the rendering engine of MS Word, so use the [standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28office.12%29.aspx) they have established for 2007 on.